# Não selecionar em caso de valor nulo em campo do banco de dados (django)

Tags: mysql, python, django

Eae rapaziada, estou com um problema, estou fazendo um script que seleciona randomicamente usuários do banco de dados:

```
select = User.objects.filter(status=0, premium=0).exclude(twitter_id=select_me.twitter_id).order_by('?').first()
```

`select_me`, seria o select do usuário que está com a sessão aberta, logo, não preciso que selecione este usuário no `random`.

Só que o gender ele armazena 1 ou 2, valores inteiros, às vezes me retorna `gender == null`, gostaria de excluir o select desses usuários que não escolheram o gênero ainda, eu tentei:

`exclude(twitter_id=select_me.twitter_id, gender=None)`

Isso não funcionou, como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma mais fácil de fazer isso é no exclude usar a condição `isnull`.

```
User.objects.exclude(twitter_id=select_me.twitter_id, gender__isnull=True)
```

Se você também precisa eliminar da query os dados vazios, mas não nulos, adicione esta outra condição:

```
exclude(gender__exact='')
```

Aqui na [documentação do Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) tem mais detalhes que podem te ajudar.

Comment: Funcionou amigão, gratidão